# Article + Possessive/Demonstrative + Noun Phrase: Acceptable in Spanish?

Tags: sustantivos, artículos, posesivos

I've come across Spanish sentences where the article is followed by a possessive adjective or demonstrative adjective, followed by a noun. Normally, it is either the article or the adjective + noun, like **el libro**, **mi libro** or **ese libro**. So, the following sentence will not be well formed: El mi/ese libro está en la mesa.

Are the following sentences well formed? How acceptable or mainstream are these sentences?

From [here](http://www.martinezdecarnero.com/glossword/index.php/term/Gonzalo+Correas%252C+Vocabulario+de+refranes,Ac%C3%A1+os+hallo%252C+amor+querido%252C+en+el+mi+libro..xhtml): Acá os hallo, amor querido, en **el mi libro**.

From [here](http://context.reverso.net/traducao/espanhol-portugues/leer+ese+libro): Voy a empezar a leer **el ese libro**.

From [here](http://www.monmagan.com/cultura/las-nuevas-criaturas-y-los-senores-jim-morrison/): yo tambien quiero **el ese libro**,por favor diganme donde lo puedo encontrar o pedir??

Comment: Asking whether a sentence is grammatical is off-topic here. You might like to visit [spanish.se], but please check whether it would be on topic there too.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I transfer this question there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, you cannot have articles and demonstratives both in front of a noun:

> ### *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009)* (p. 1380)
>
> **19.1j** El artículo, los demostrativos y los posesivos se excluyen mutuamente como introductores del grupo nominal, **con excepciones** […]

But there are exceptions and so we can say that for the first one, **yes**.

Modern Spanish normally does not use the structure *article + unstressed possessive pronoun + noun*, but it is still in common use in some parts of the Spanish-speaking world:

> ### *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009)* (p. 1347)
>
> **18.2n** […] Las principales pautas en las que los posesivos seguían a otros modificadores del sustantivo son las siguientes:
>
> A. «Artículo definido + posesivo»  […]
>    B. «Artículo indefinido + posesivo» […]
>
> **18.3m** […] Las pautas *A* y *B*, muy comunes en la lengua medieval, fueron cayendo en desuso en la clásica, especialmente la primera.  Ambas pervivieron, sin embargo, en las hablas septentrionales y noroccidentales de la Península Ibérica […] La pauta *B* (*un su amigo, una mi hijita*) se documenta hoy en la misma área.  También se registra en México, en particular en el estado de Chiapas, así como en varios países centroamericanos, especialmente Guatemala, Nicaragua y El Salvador.  Se atestigua asimismo en el Paraguay y en el área de Cajamarca (Perú), entre otras regiones andinas.

For the second two, **no**, at least not generally in the example you've given (that is, *article + demonstrative adjective from the este/ese/aquel series + noun*), though it [can be](https://books.google.ch/books?id=vyDnAtYApD4C&lpg=PA36&ots=02Hy_CfcmW&dq=%22las%20aquellas%20cosas%22&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q=%22las%20aquellas%20cosas%22&f=false) in [medieval](https://books.google.ch/books?id=lDaqJTp8xJEC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22las%20aquellas%20cosas%22&source=bl&ots=5q48vEWwFq&sig=ORPWX9nJVfwpJEZr1vU5AmxeZMw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22las%20aquellas%20cosas%22&f=false) Spanish and even in [modern](https://books.google.ch/books?id=h-ba8pzFn2wC&pg=PA12&dq=%22el%20este%20libro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFz9r1r_HLAhWGtxQKHYI_DtMQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22el%20este%20libro%22&f=false) Spanish [occasionally](https://books.google.ch/books?id=Aly9i--7CDkC&pg=PA65&dq=%22los%20esos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW7Z2nsfHLAhVJvhQKHS5bCPI4KBDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=%22los%20esos%22&f=false) (though it may be hard to tell the difference between a typo and intentional use in the modern).  The demonstrative adjective *tal* does, however, easily admit such construction in modern Spanish:

> ### *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009)* (p. 1329-30)
>
> **17.10l** Se emplea *tal* como adjetivo antepuesto cuando aparece precedido de un determinante.  Este uso era muy común en el español medieval y en el clásico, pero se registra asimismo en el actual, algo más frecuentemente en el español americano que en el europeo.
>   […]
>   **17.10n** La pauta «*un tal* o *una tal* + nombre común» era común en la lengua medieval […] Aunque esta construcción es hoy poco habitual, se registra en el español europeo y el americano, con frecuencia algo mayor en el segundo que en el primero.

Comment: Wow. Your answer is more comprehensive, but I have already accepted an answer :(

Comment: @Noble_Bright_Life you can change your mind after accepting am answer. Just click the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

Those sentences are not well formed, with the only exception of the structure *article + possessive + noun*, which is very rarely used in poetic language. It used to be a correct structure long time ago though.

Comment: The first sentence is perfectly current in modern Spanish.  See § 18.3m *Nueva gramática de la lengua española (2009)* (p. 1347).